# fetch images using picasso in adapter from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a recycleview which fetches data from api with a custom adapter containing a textview and imageview and I implemented this in Activity and it works fine, but now I tried to use fragment instead of activity and every thing works fine except for the images that are not displayed after moving the code to fragment so this is my fragment:

```
public class TVFragment extends Fragment implements TVAdapter.TVAdapterOnClickHandler {

    TVAdapter mAdapter;

    RecyclerView mSportsList;

    String sortsports="sports.php";

    Context mContext ;

    public static TVFragment newInstance() {
        TVFragment fragment = new TVFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tv, container, false);

        mSportsList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_sports);

        mContext = getActivity();

        GridLayoutManager LayoutManagerSports = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3);
        mSportsList.setLayoutManager(LayoutManagerSports);
        mSportsList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mAdapter = new TVAdapter(this, mContext);
        mSportsList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        loadTVData(sortsports);
        return view;
    }

    private void loadTVData(String sortChannels) {
        showTVDataView();
        new FetchTVTask().execute(sortChannels);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(TVItem channel) {
        Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        Class destinationClass = TVChannel.class;
        Intent intentToStartDetailActivity = new Intent(context, destinationClass);
        intentToStartDetailActivity.putExtra("TVChannel", channel);
        startActivity(intentToStartDetailActivity);
    }

    private void showTVDataView() {
        mSportsList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }


    public class FetchTVTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<TVItem>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<TVItem> doInBackground(String... params) {
            if (params.length == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            String sortChannels = params[0];
            URL channelRequestUrl = NetworkTV.buildUrl(sortChannels);

            try {
                String jsonTVResponse = NetworkTV.getResponseFromHttpUrl(channelRequestUrl);

                ArrayList<TVItem> simpleJsonTVData = JsonTV.getSimpleTVStringsFromJson(getContext(), jsonTVResponse);

                return simpleJsonTVData;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<TVItem> TVData) {
            if (TVData != null) {
                showTVDataView();
                mAdapter.setTVData(TVData);
            } else {
            }
        }
    }

}
```

then this is my adapter:

```
public class TVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TVAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<TVItem> mChannelItems;
    private Context mContext;
    private final TVAdapter.TVAdapterOnClickHandler mClickHandler;

    public interface TVAdapterOnClickHandler {
        void onClick(TVItem channel);
    }

    public TVAdapter(TVAdapterOnClickHandler clickHandler, Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        mClickHandler = clickHandler;
    }

    class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public final TextView Cat;
        public final ImageView Image;

        public RecyclerViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            Cat = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.channel_cat);
            Image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.channel_image);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int adapterPosition = getAdapterPosition();
            TVItem channel = mChannelItems.get(adapterPosition);
            mClickHandler.onClick(channel);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public TVAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        mContext = viewGroup.getContext();
        int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.tv_list_item;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        boolean shouldAttachToParentImmediately = false;

        View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, viewGroup, shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
        return new TVAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TVAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(mChannelItems.get(position).getFullImagePath()).resize(500,500).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).error(R.drawable.placeholder).into(holder.Image);
        holder.Cat.setText(String.valueOf(mChannelItems.get(position).getTitle()));
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (null == mChannelItems)
            return 0;
        else {
            return mChannelItems.size();
        }
    }

    public void setTVData(ArrayList<TVItem> TVData) {
        mChannelItems = TVData;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

you can see these lines:

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(mChannelItems.get(position).getFullImagePath()).resize(500,500).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).error(R.drawable.placeholder).into(holder.Image);
```

and:

`holder.Cat.setText(String.valueOf(mChannelItems.get(position).getTitle()));`

the cat still displayed well in textview but the images with picasso library not displayed anymore and I read a lot of solutions like pass the context from fragment to adapter but nothing work!

this is the debugging images:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

viewgroup.getContext() Isn't the context needed, but the context from the fragment or an activity.

```
@Override
public TVAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    //mContext = viewGroup.getContext(); This should fix it. You already init mContext in the constructor.
    int layoutIdForListItem = R.layout.tv_list_item;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    boolean shouldAttachToParentImmediately = false;

    View view = inflater.inflate(layoutIdForListItem, viewGroup, shouldAttachToParentImmediately);
    return new TVAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder(view);

}
```

Comment: I already try to remove the mContext = viewGroup.getContext(); but nothing change the images still didn't appear

Comment: @GNDevs strange try using Picasso.with(Context).setLoggingEnabled(true) to check for any error messages in the logger.

Comment: like this? `Picasso.with(mContext).setLoggingEnabled(true).load(mChannelItems.get(position).getFullImagePath()).resize(500,500).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).error(R.drawable.placeholder).into(holder.Image);`
it says that cannot resolve method 'load(android.net.Uri)'

Comment: can you check the mChannelItems.get(position).getFullImagePath() value maybe something is mistypes.

Comment: I add a debug point to picasso line and add the screenshots to the original post so check it please the images received well as I see and as I said before the images was displayed well when the code was in activity but the problem start only with fragment

Comment: As much as i see everything seams correct but can you press the + symbol in the debugger and type mChannelItems.get(0).getTitle().

Comment: sure I add the screenshot to original post too see it please

Comment: sorry my bad i mis-copied the one i needed meant getFullImagePath()

Comment: I guess that :D
I add the screenshot to post now

Comment: I have typed http://tvbg.giganet.iq/uploads/max1.png in a web browser there was no image. may you check on your side if there is an image?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174229/discussion-between-mohammad-tabbara-and-gndevs).

Comment: it's private server that's why it doesn't appear to you, thanks for helping it's working finally you saved my day

Answer (score 1):

Why are you assigning value to `mContext` twice? Try removing `mContext = viewGroup.getContext();` from code.

Comment: I already try to remove the mContext = viewGroup.getContext(); but nothing change the images still didn't appear

Comment: Instead of using `context = getActivity()` in fragment, try `view.getContext()`.

Comment: `mContext = view.getContext();` 
I tried this now but it's the same images still not displayed :(

Comment: Okay, then finally I would suggest putting a debug point on that line to check whether getter is returning proper data.

Comment: I add a debug point to picasso line and add the screenshots to the original post so check it please the images received well as I see

Comment: Are you sure that image url is correct?, because it is not a valid link as I check in my browser.

Comment: Can you try commenting your Picasso statement and create new duplicate line with some dummy png url from internet.. see if it shows up, if it does then probably wrong url.

Comment: it's private server that's why it doesn't appear to you, thanks for helping